# Exclude element and its descendants from DOM selection

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-selectors

How can I select all DOM elements except for a given element and its descendants with CSS or jQuery?

Say the given element is #test

`$('#test *')` will return all #test descendants

--but--

`$('* :not(#test))')` OR `$('* :not(#test *))')` OR `$('*').not('#test')` OR `$('*').not('#test *')`

do not work!

**EDIT:**
I want to trigger a click event when clicking anywhere on the page but the `#test` area.

Comment: For what purpose? The purpose affects the answer we should give.

Comment: I want to trigger a click event when clicking anywhere on the page but the `#test` area.

Comment: Did you try this `$("*").not("div#test > *")`

Comment: Yes I did. But this is ONLY for the direct children while I need to exclude ALL descendants of `#test`, regardless of depth.

Comment: The selector for this would be `:not(#test, #test *)`, and it only works as a jQuery selector. You don't just use one of them ("OR"); rather you need to combine two of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to trigger a click event when clicking anywhere on the page but the `#test` area.

Then you don't need to bind click to every element... just bind to the document and check if it's `$('#test, #test *')` that's being hit and if so, abort the click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#test, #test *')) {
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff
});
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/hLEYn)

Comment: Instead of `body` I used `document` and all worked fine. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @laxris: Yes, I realized `body` doesn't quite cut it. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In your click event check if the click was within `#test`: http://jsfiddle.net/QDNCS/

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$('#test')[0].contains(e.target)) {
        alert('Yay!');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The System Restart was close:

```
$('*').not('#test, #test *')
```

Nonetheless I wouldn't bind an event to that selector -- it could select too many element and make your site work sluggish. If it happens consider using jquery's `live()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact jQuery code for this, but this jQuery script seems to be what you are looking for.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the answers from @The System Restart and @topp to get the requested behavior:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is('#test, #test *')) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Note I haven't tested this code.